# Cucumber (Java) via Windows command line works via batch, but not pom

Tags: java, windows, maven, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I'm running through the examples in the [Cucumber For Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1941222293) book on the Windows command line. I can execute it fine from a Windows batch file, but when attempting to do it from Maven, I'm getting "No sources to compile" and "No tests to run". What is needed in the pom to point to the same classes/features as in the batch?

Full output:

```
[C:\data_jeffy\code\java\cucumber\learning_cucumber\first_taste\checkout]mvn clean test
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Checkout Groceries Example 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ checkout-groceries-example ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ checkout-groceries-example --
-
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platf
orm dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\data_jeffy\code\java\cucumber\learning_cucumber\first
_taste\checkout\src\main\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ checkout-groceries-example ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ checkout-groceries-ex
ample ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platf
orm dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\data_jeffy\code\java\cucumber\learning_cucumber\first
_taste\checkout\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ checkout-groceries-example
 ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.2:test (default-test) @ checkout-groceries-example ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.727 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-05-10T13:45:48-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/155M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

`checkout/pom.xml`:

```
<!--
 ! Excerpted from "The Cucumber for Java Book",
 ! published by The Pragmatic Bookshelf.
 ! Copyrights apply to this code. It may not be used to create training material,
 ! courses, books, articles, and the like. Contact us if you are in doubt.
 ! We make no guarantees that this code is fit for any purpose.
 ! Visit http://www.pragmaticprogrammer.com/titles/srjcuc for more book information.
-->
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>uk.co.claysnow</groupId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>Checkout Groceries Example</name>
    <artifactId>checkout-groceries-example</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <cucumber.version>1.2.0</cucumber.version>
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>-Duser.language=en</argLine>
                    <argLine>-Xmx1024m</argLine>
                    <argLine>-XX:MaxPermSize=256m</argLine>
                    <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
                    <useFile>false</useFile>
                </configuration>
             </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

`checkout/features/checkout.feature`:

```
Feature: Checkout
    Scenario: Checkout a banana
        Given the price of a "banana" is 40c
        When I checkout 1 "banana"
        Then the total price should be 40c
    Scenario Outline: Checkout bananas
        Given the price of a "banana" is 40c
        When I checkout <count> "banana"
        Then the total price should be <total>c
        Examples:
        | count | total |
        | 1     | 40    |
        | 2     | 80    |
    Scenario: Two bananas scanned separately
        Given the price of a "banana" is 40c
        When I checkout 1 "banana"
        And I checkout 1 "banana"
        Then the total price should be 80c
    Scenario: A banana and an apple
        Given the price of a "banana" is 40c
        When I checkout 1 "banana"
        And I checkout 1 "apple"
        Then the total price should be 65c
```

`checkout/checkout.bat`:

```
@(
set JAR_DIR=C:\data_jeffy\code\java\cucumber\learning_cucumber\first_taste\checkout\jars\
set CLASSPATH=%JAR_DIR%gherkin-2.12.2.jar;%JAR_DIR%cucumber-jvm-deps-1.0.3.jar;%JAR_DIR%cucumber-java-1.2.2.jar;%JAR_DIR%cucumber-core-1.2.2.jar;%JAR_DIR%junit-4.11.jar;.
)
javac -cp %CLASSPATH% step_definitions/CheckoutSteps.java implementation/Checkout.java
@(
REM java -cp %CLASSPATH% cucumber.api.cli.Main --help
)
java -cp %CLASSPATH% cucumber.api.cli.Main -p progress --snippets camelcase -g step_definitions features
```

Comment: Is your directory structure in compliance with what Maven expects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using cucumber-jvm with Maven, the project needs to respect the Maven conventions so that cucumber-jvm can pick up the different files.  If using `maven-surefire-plugin`:

- The feature files need to be stored in `src/test/resources`;
- The step definitions need to be stored in `src/test/java`;
- The unit test(s) annotated with the `@RunWith(Cucumber.class)` annotation need to be stored in `src/test/java`.

Tests can then be executed running `mvn test`.  You can check out [this example](https://github.com/tychobrailleur/cucumber-jvm-examples/tree/master/checkout) I have put on github.

Comment: Of course. The book does not make this clear, and since I'm a Maven newbie as well, it didn't occur to me. Thank you.